# how to Display Json Data in dropdownlist in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON file with data that I want to display in my dropdownlist. How do I go about implementing this? I would appreciate any input. I currently have this hardcoded into my page unndes state and working but want to call it from json file. I've tried some answers on here with no luck. This is one of the errors that I got: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'` Changing the code and moving stuff around only gave more errors.

````
class SearchFilters extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchFiltersState createState() => _SearchFiltersState();
}


class _SearchFiltersState extends State<SearchFilters> {

     var _propType = ["Free Standing", "Town House", "Apartment", "Vacant Land", "Ofiice", "Farm", "New Development"];
     var _currentItemPropery = "Free Standing";
     var _town = ["Rehoboth", "Windhoek", "Swakopmund", "Walvisbay", "Keetmanshoop", "Otjiwarongo"];
     var _currentItemTown = "Rehoboth";
     var _minPrice = ["N\$ 10.00", "N\$ 20.00", "N\$ 30.00", "N\$ 40.00", "N\$ 50.00"];
     var _currentItemMinPrice = "N\$ 10.00";
     var _maxPrice = ["N\$ 100.00", "N\$ 200.00", "N\$ 300.00", "N\$ 400.00", "N\$ 500.00"];
     var _currentItemMaxPrice = "N\$ 100.00";
     var _minBeds = ["1", "2"];
     var _currentItemMinBeds = "1";
     var _maxBeds = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
     var _currentItemMaxBeds = "1";
     var _baths = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
     var _currentItemBaths = "1";
     var _parking = ["1", "2", "3"];
     var _currentItemParking = "1";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
//          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
//          todo =========== Property Type =====================
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Property Type",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      ),
                    )),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                          width: 2.0,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    items: _propType.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(
                          dropDownStringItem,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                      setState(() {
                        this._currentItemPropery = newValueSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _currentItemPropery,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    isExpanded: true,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12.0,
                ),
//          todo =========== Towns =====================
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    "Town",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                          width: 2.0,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    items: _town.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(
                          dropDownStringItem,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                      setState(() {
                        this._currentItemTown = newValueSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _currentItemTown,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    isExpanded: true,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12.0,
                ),
//          todo =========== Min Price =====================
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "Min Price",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              width: 2.0,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        items: _minPrice.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: dropDownStringItem,
                            child: Text(
                              dropDownStringItem,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              this._currentItemMinPrice = newValueSelected;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        value: _currentItemMinPrice,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        iconSize: 40.0,
//                      isExpanded: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
//          todo =========== Max Price =====================
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "Max Price",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              width: 2.0,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        items: _maxPrice.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: dropDownStringItem,
                            child: Text(
                              dropDownStringItem,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              this._currentItemMaxPrice = newValueSelected;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        value: _currentItemMaxPrice,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        iconSize: 40.0,
//                      isExpanded: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
//              todo ================== Min Bedrooms =====================
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Min Bedrooms",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2.0,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                    color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              items: _minBeds.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: dropDownStringItem,
                                  child: Text(
                                    dropDownStringItem,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                                setState(() {
                                  this._currentItemMinBeds = newValueSelected;
                                });
                              },
                              value: _currentItemMinBeds,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              iconSize: 40.0,
                              isExpanded: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
//              todo ================== Max Bedrooms =====================
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Max Bedrooms",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2.0,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                    color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              items: _maxBeds.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: dropDownStringItem,
                                  child: Text(
                                    dropDownStringItem,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                                setState(() {
                                  this._currentItemMaxBeds = newValueSelected;
                                });
                              },
                              value: _currentItemMaxBeds,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              iconSize: 40.0,
                              isExpanded: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
//              todo ================== Bathrooms =====================
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Bathrooms",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2.0,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                    color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              items:
                                  _baths.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: dropDownStringItem,
                                  child: Text(
                                    dropDownStringItem,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                                setState(() {
                                  this._currentItemBaths = newValueSelected;
                                });
                              },
                              value: _currentItemBaths,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              iconSize: 40.0,
                              isExpanded: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
//              todo ================== Parking =====================
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Car Spaces",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2.0,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                    color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              items:
                                  _parking.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: dropDownStringItem,
                                  child: Text(
                                    dropDownStringItem,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                                setState(() {
                                  this._currentItemParking = newValueSelected;
                                });
                              },
                              value: _currentItemParking,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              iconSize: 40.0,
                              isExpanded: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24.0),
//              todo ================= Mail Button ====================
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  child: ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 50,
                    splashColor: Colors.white30,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      elevation: 5.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      child: Text(
                        "SEARCH",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are decoding the json as shown above, you need to use something like:

```
void parseJson() async {
  var decode = json.decode(theJson);
  var types = decode[0]['prop_type']; // List<dynamic>
  _propTypes = List<String>.from(types); // List<String>
  ...
  setState((){});
}
```

(Prefer camelCase for variable names.)

`List.from` is a handy way to change the type of a list. Remember that the whole structure of json where the right hand side of a value can be a bool, int, string, array, object means that the json decoder has to make things dynamic in Dart.

Now your `map` to create `items` should work.

Comment: thank you again, but i get an error on ```decode``` and ```types``` in .from(types) giving ```only static members can be accessed in initializer``` I updated the post with my full working code as i have it now... want to call the same data from search.json in my assests how do implement your code into this. thanks.

Comment: To be clear, these lines have to be part of a method, which you will call from `initState`. In that method you can get the JSON, parse it, and assign the results to your variables (e.g. `_propTypes`). Having assigned the values you need to call `setState` as the state has changed. In your `build` you need to make one change: at the beginning, if `_propTypes` is null, that means that the json isn't parse yet (and your `.map`s will fail) - so simply return `CircularProgressIndicator()`. As soon as the json is parsed, the framework will call `build` again, and page will draw OK as lists are valid

Comment: Thanks @RichardHeap you are a great help as always... Much appreciated I still have allot to learn...